# React native factory pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have two text input types in my app. The search input, and the other text inputs (for forms, comments...) which can have an icon.

The search input receive an onSubmit (for the keyboard) that is used too in the touchable opacity of its icon. The other text inputs don't have an onSubmit prop, but their icons can have an onPress function.

I have never implemented the factory pattern on React, shall I use it? If not, should I generalize the  text input component? Or is it okay to have the two components?

What do you think?

Search Input:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Keyboard, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { TextInput, useTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function SearchInput(props) {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  let { placeholder, maxLength, color, onSearch } = props;

  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  if (!color) {
    color = colors.white;
  }

  const handleChangeText = (text) => {
    setText(text);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    onSearch(text);
    // Close the keyboard
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={placeholder}
          value={text}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          dense
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          selectionColor={colors.primary}
          onChangeText={handleChangeText}
          onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
          style={[styles.input, { backgroundColor: color }]}
        />
        <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={styles.iconContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={handleSubmit}>
            <Icon name="search" type="material" color={colors.gray} size={20} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

SearchInput.propTypes = {
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  maxLength: PropTypes.number,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  onSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

SearchInput.defaultProps = {
  maxLength: 30,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  input: {
    paddingRight: 5,
    fontSize: 14,
    padding: 5,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    marginRight: 5,
  },
});
```

Other text inputs:

```
import React, { useState, forwardRef } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { TextInput as RNPTextInput, useTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TextInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  let {
    placeholder,
    multiline,
    maxLength,
    color,
    icon,
    counter,
    onSubmit,
  } = props;

  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  if (!color) {
    color = colors.white;
  }

  // Default props for optional nested object
  if (icon) {
    if (!icon.color) {
      icon.color = colors.gray;
    }

    if (!icon.size) {
      icon.size = 20;
    }

    if (!icon.onPress) {
      icon.onPress = () => {};
    }
  }

  const handleChangeText = (text) => {
    setText(text);
  };

  const handleIconPress = () => {
    const { onPress } = icon;
    onPress();
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    onSubmit(text);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <RNPTextInput
          ref={ref}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          value={text}
          multiline={multiline}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          maxHeight={85}
          dense
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          selectionColor={colors.primary}
          onChangeText={handleChangeText}
          style={[styles.input, { backgroundColor: color }]}
          onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
        />
        {icon && (
          <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={styles.iconContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={handleIconPress}>
              <Icon
                name={icon.name}
                type={icon.type}
                color={icon.color}
                size={icon.size}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
      {counter && (
        <View style={styles.charactersCounterContainer}>
          <Text style={[styles.charactersCounter, { color: colors.gray }]}>
            {`${text.length}/${maxLength}`}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </>
  );
});

TextInput.propTypes = {
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  multiline: PropTypes.bool,
  maxLength: PropTypes.number,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  icon: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    size: PropTypes.number,
    onPress: PropTypes.func,
  }),
  counter: PropTypes.bool,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
};

TextInput.defaultProps = {
  placeholder: null,
  multiline: false,
  maxLength: 300,
  icon: null,
  counter: false,
  onSubmit: () => {},
};

export default TextInput;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  input: {
    paddingRight: 5,
    fontSize: 14,
    padding: 5,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  charactersCounterContainer: {
    marginTop: 5,
    width: "100%",
  },
  charactersCounter: {
    textAlign: "right",
    fontSize: 12,
  },
});
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code you have so far (i.e. update the question)? It's easier to think about what you mean that way :)

Comment: Yes of course. You can see it now in the post.

Comment: Pd: React native paper text inputs still don't support icons as a prop... That's why I've done this stuff